# Check deferred constraints before commit

Tags: postgresql, transactions, constraints

Is there a way to check all deferred constraints **before** commit?

Here's my situation. My system imports data rows that reference each other. The rows may or may not be imported in the correct order to reference existing rows. In some instances the rows even have circular references, so there's no way to import them when referential integrity is maintained with each new record.

So far, no problem. Deferred constraints were created for situations like that.

Here's the problem.  After all the data has been imported, but before commit, I need to run some more checks on the data. Those checks only work after all the data has been imported and the foreign keys checked.

So what I'd like to do is something like this:

1. import the data
2. check all contraints
3. run some more checks
4. commit or rollback as necessary

From my (hopefully inaccurate) reading of the docs, the only way to check deferred constraints is to either commit or to run my own custom constraint checkers. Neither is a very appealing option.

Advice?